# cython issue: 'bool' is not a type identifier

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm desperately trying to expose a `std::vector<bool>` class member to a Python class.

Here is my C++ class:

```
class Test
{
  public:
    std::vector<bool> test_fail;
    std::vector<double> test_ok;
};
```

While the access and conversion of `test_ok` of type `double` (or int, float, ..) works, it does not for `bool`!

Here is my Cython class:

```
cdef class pyTest:
     cdef Test* thisptr
     cdef public vector[bool] test_fail
     cdef public vector[double] test_ok

     cdef __cinit__(self):
         self.thisptr = new Test()
         self.test_fail = self.thisptr.test_fail # compiles and works if commented
         self.test_ok = self.thisptr.test_ok

     cdef __dealloc__(self):
         del self.thisptr
```

The error I get is :

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...




cdef extern from *:
    ctypedef bool X 'bool'
            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

vector.from_py:37:13: 'bool' is not a type identifier
```

I'm using python 2.7.6 and Cython 0.20.2 (also tried 0.20.1).

I also tried with properties but it does not work either.

**Addendum:** I do have the `from libcpp cimport bool` at the top of my pyx file, as well as the vector import.

What's wrong ?? I believe this might be a bug. Anyone knows how to circumvent this ? Thanks.

Comment: The Cython wiki is quite helpful regarding this issue: https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#id49

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a valid workaround, although it may not be optimal.

I have replaced the members types of the `pytest` class with python lists.

The conversion is now done implicitly, as described in the documentation: https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library

> All conversions create a new container and copy the data into it. The items in the containers are converted to a corresponding type automatically, which includes recursively converting containers inside of containers, e.g. a C++ vector of maps of strings.

So now, my class looks like this:

```
cdef class pyTest:
     cdef Test* thisptr
     cdef public list test_fail #now ok
     cdef public list test_ok

     cdef __cinit__(self):
         self.thisptr = new Test()
         self.test_fail = self.thisptr.test_fail # implicit copy & conversion
         self.test_ok = self.thisptr.test_ok # implicit copy and conversion

     cdef __dealloc__(self):
         del self.thisptr
```

Answer (score 77):

There's some extra C++ support you need to do. At the top of your .pyx file, add

```
from libcpp cimport bool
```

I'd take a look inside that to find the other things you might need, like std::string and STL containers

Comment: Can't seem to edit my answer: add `from libcpp.vector cimport vector` for the vector keyword

Comment: hello, I forgot to mention that I do have the `cimport bool` in the top of my pyx file :(

Comment: I think I misread. It seems to be complaining about the `'bool'` typedef. It's unnecessary IMO. If you've imported bool, you can declare any bool variable with `cdef bool x`

Comment: `from libcpp cimport bool as bool_t` would be better to solve the naming conflict with Python's bool.

Answer (score 51):

In order to define `boolean` objects in cython, they need to be defined as `bint`. According to [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/DifferencesFromPyrex): The bint of "boolean int" object is compiled to a c int, but get coerced to and from Cython as booleans.

Example:

```
cdef bint boolean_variable = True
```

source: [types bint](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#types)