# how to declare numpy.bool in cython?

Tags: python, numpy

According the offical doc:
http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html
we should "ctypedef" a corresponding compile-time type,but I tried several methods to deal with numpy.bool. It's still wrong.

**1.**

```
DTYPE2 = np.bool

ctypedef np.bool_t DTYPE2_t
```

> raise: 'bool_t' is not a type identifier

**2.**

```
DTYPE2 = np.bint

ctypedef np.bint_t DTYPE2_t
```

> raise: 'bint_t' is not a type identifier

**3.**
add on the top of the .pyx file:

```
from libcpp cimport bool
#? As recommended by McKelvin in  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659723/cython-issue-bool-is-not-a-type-identifier][2]
#from libcpp cimport bool_t 
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
```

no helpful!

**4.**
I've seen the post:
[Declaring a numpy boolean mask in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088886/declaring-a-numpy-boolean-mask-in-cython)
**But I need define the variable in function's parameter to pass a numpy.bool array in.**

```
def Func(np.ndarray[np.bool_t, ndim=1] f)

## def Func(np.ndarray[np.bool, ndim=1] f)
```

> raise:
> Invalid type

**5.**
ignore the declare? It seems necessory in function's parameters according the offical doc if I want to speedup it:

```
def naive_convolve(np.ndarray[**DTYPE_t**, ndim=2] f, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] g):
```

So what should I do with numpy.bool?

My test is based on the following simple codes:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

DTYPE2 = np.bint
ctypedef np.bint_t DTYPE2_t
def Func(np.ndarray[DTYPE2_t, ndim=1] npdata):
    print(npdata)
```

cython: the most recent version

windows7 OS

I'm sure cython was installed correctly.It can work well when there isn't np.bool.

Answer (score 7):

The name of the numpy boolean ctype is `npy_bool`. So the correct version of your test code would be:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

def Func(np.ndarray[np.npy_bool, ndim=1, cast=True] npdata):
    print(npdata)
    return npdata
```

Note the `cast=True` above (I also added a return statement for testing purposes). Here's some code testing `Func` out:

```
arr = np.random.randint(0,2, size=3, dtype=int)
boolArr = np.array(arr, dtype=bool)

# Func(arr)                     # raises "ValueError: Item size of buffer (8 bytes) does not match size of 'npy_bool' (1 byte)"
returnArr = Func(boolArr)
assert returnArr.dtype is np.dtype(bool)
```

#### note about `cast`

Without the `cast` keyword, you get a really weird error message when you try to call `Func`:

```
ValueError: Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('?')
```

Diving into the [Cython source code](https://github.com/telamonian/cython/blob/0.28.1/Cython/Utility/Buffer.c) gives a bit of insight into the above `ValueError`. One of the representations of dtypes that Numpy uses is ["array-protocol type strings"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#index-6). The one for bool is `'?'`. Many of these can be specified using a number, like `'4i'`, which represents how many bytes a single element of that type requires. Cython apparently interprets array types according to this string, [and expects there to be a number](https://github.com/telamonian/cython/blob/89cfbb4a3a0540abeec1703fd3ee31eba9293936/Cython/Utility/Buffer.c#L625), which it seems Numpy doesn't supply for bool. Probably just something (in either Numpy or Cython) needs a bugfix somewhere.

## Update

The `cast=True` argument might not be needed for much longer. I submitted a [pull request with a fix to Cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/2676), and it seems to be wending its way through.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! That's what I want

Comment: Interesting. The bug is still here! Thanks for writing the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Ginger I just submitted a [PR with a fix to Cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/2676), so hopefully the bug will be gone soon.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! Do you know how to then access this array via a memoryview?